# How do I verify this equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

On Wikipedia I found the heat kernal with neuman condtions

\begin{cases} u_{t}=ku_{xx} & (x, t) \in [0, \infty) \times (0, \infty) \\ u(x,0)=g(x) & IC \\ u_{x}(0,t)=0 & BC \end{cases}

$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)+\exp\left(-\frac{(x+y)^2}{4kt}\right)\right]g(y)\,dy $

I am trying to verify the neuman condition. But when I let x=0 obviously the exponents don;t add to zero, so what am I missing? Also, how do I set a reflection boundary to an arbitrary variable instead of x=0? I read a paper that used a fourier series in the proof, but I would prefer a closed form solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the problem on the whole real line, without the boundary condition; then the solution is
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi k t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)\exp\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt} dy.$$
The homogeneous Neumann boundary condition is a symmetry condition. If you define $g(x)=g(-x)$ for $x<0$, i.e., continue $g$ as an even function, the above formula gives the solution.

Now suppose the boundary condition is $\left. u_x \right|_{x=a}=0$ and $g$ be defined for $x>a$, then define $g(x)=g(2a-x)$ for $x<a$ and voila. The integral can be rewritten in the form
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi k t}}\left[\int_{a}^{\infty}g(y)\exp\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt} dy + \int_{-\infty}^a g(2a-y)\exp\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt} dy \right].$$